# How to calculate CPU usage in Cadvisor to be equal to docker stats

Tags: docker, prometheus, cadvisor

I have a cpu usage data in Cadvisor (12 cores) .
But I want to calculate to be equal to docker stats.

First time I use this query but it's not work because the value in Prometheus not be the same with docker stats and I want the value to percentage.

```
rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{name="XXXX"}[1m])
```

What should I do to calculate?

Answer (score 0):

[docker stats](https://docs.docker.com/reference/cli/docker/container/stats/) shows instant CPU usage at the current time, while [cadvisor](https://github.com/google/cadvisor) exports the total CPU time used by the particular container via `container_cpu_usage_seconds_total` metric. Such metric type is called [counter](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyconcepts/#counter). Prometheus scrapes `cadvisor` metrics with the configured interval, which is called `scrape_interval`. It can be configured in `prometheus.yaml` file at `global` section or individually per each [scrape_config](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/sd_configs/#scrape_configs) section. By default it is set to one minute.

This means that Prometheus doesn't collect instant CPU usage for each container from `cadvisor`. Instead, it collects the total per-container CPU usage every `scrape_interval`. So it can calculate only an **average** CPU usage over the `scrape_interval` or over any interval bigger than the `scrape_interval`. The [rate](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/metricsql/#rate) function must be used for calculating the average CPU usage over the given interval specified in square brackets. For example, `rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total[5m])` returns the average per-container CPU usage over the last 5 minutes.

P.S. Note that [irate](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/metricsql/#irate) function doesn't return an instant CPU usage - it returns the **average** CPU usage over the last two scrapes. For example, if the `scrape_interval` equals to 30 seconds, then `irate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total[5m])` returns average CPU usage over the last 30 seconds. See also [this article](https://valyala.medium.com/why-irate-from-prometheus-doesnt-capture-spikes-45f9896d7832).

Comment: If I want real time data for CPU usage from docker contrainer that I focus how can I collect metrics to visualize in grafana. I don't have to use Cadvisor . Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Take a look at [netdata](https://www.netdata.cloud/)